# Getting Mac system temperatures with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, hardware, cpu

How do I access the system temperatures and fan speeds of a Mac using Objective-C? I have seen it done in applications like iStat, but I can not figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4):

You may also take a look at https://github.com/fmorrow/SMCWrapper - it's an object-oriented version of smc.c/smc.h. (The code of SMCWrapper is well commented)
Currently, it opens a connection using IOKit to AppleSMC IOService, and uses it to makes calls to the SMC chip. You can read keys to NSString, but setting key value is experimental at this time.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree - and I'm gonna add explanations. But Joe's answer has the same problem...

Comment: Thanks! I really needed the fan speed part.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp/blob/master/smc.c for sample code that reads the temps from the SMC.